# Microsoft Codename "Data Transfer" identity column error

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, etl, data-transfer

I'm using [Microsoft Codename "Data Transfer"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazurelabs/labs/datatransfer.aspx) to transfer data from an Excel (or cvs) file to a SQL Azure database. Everything runs through normally, but when it comes to uploading the data this error is thrown for each row:

> Exception while loading data into Table: [dbo.Xxxx].
>   ErrorMessage: [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Xxxx' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.].
>   Error data is logged in the ErrorLogTable [ErrorLog_xxxxxxxxxxxxx] in the destination database. RefId: [xxxxxxxx], Line# around [x]

I've tried several ways of setting up the column mappings in the analyze part of the wizard which include (and all result in the above error:)

- Mapping an Id column in Excel (which is null) to the Id column in the database
- Mapping the RowId(auto-generated) column to the Id column in the database

This will be an awesome tool once it's working.... or at least idiot-proof!

**Update:**

The obvious solution is not mapping anything to the `Id` column and this is the first thing I tried, but it is not allowed to leave the `Id` unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the problem here... the message is clear, you need to set identity insert to "on" for this column.  Then you will be able to leave the ID column mapped and insert it.

Comment: There is no place to do that in the SQL Azure portal. In any case I think it was a bug that they fixed